# kartik datepicker

Tags: php, yii2, datepicker, bs4, kartik

Yii2 Bootstrap 4

```
use kartik\field\FieldRange;
use kartik\form\ActiveForm;
use kartik\datecontrol\DateControl;
                   <div class="text-center">
                        <span class="h4 secondary-color">Create new budget</span>
                    </div>
                    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['class' => 'user mt-5']]); ?>
                    <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['style' => 'height: 50px; border-radius: 10rem;', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Budget name'])->label(false); ?>
                    <?= $form->field($model, 'amount')->input('number', ['style' => 'height: 50px; border-radius: 10rem;', 'class' => ' form-control mb-4', 'step' => '0.01',  'placeholder' => 'Amount'])->label(false); ?>
                    <?= $form->field($model, 'wallet')->dropDownList($wItems, ['prompt' => 'Select wallet', 'style' => 'height:50px; border-radius: 10rem;', 'class' => 'custom-select'])->label(false); ?>
                    <?= FieldRange::widget([
                        'form' => $form,
                        'model' => $model,
                        'label' => 'Enter date range',
                        'attribute1' => 'date_start',
                        'attribute2' => 'date_end',
                        'type' => FieldRange::INPUT_WIDGET,
                        'widgetClass' => DateControl::class,
                        'widgetOptions1' => [
                            'saveFormat' => 'php:U'
                        ],
                        'widgetOptions2' => [
                            'saveFormat' => 'php:U'
                        ],
                    ]);?>

                    <hr>
                    <div class="text-right">
                        <?= Html::submitButton('', ['class' => 'btn fa fa-check fa-lg mt-2']) ?>
                    </div>

                    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Не работает выбор дат, получается вот так 
[image: result]

Также выбрать дату не получается, почему-то таблица с выбором просто не появляется (только края, видно на 2 скриншоте)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать другой datapicker. Загрузите в composer 
"moonlandsoft/bootui-datetimepicker": "*"

В форме выглядит так:

```
use bootui\datetimepicker\Datepicker;

<?= $form->field($model, 'birthdate')->widget(DatePicker::className(), [
           'options' => ['class' => 'form-control'],
           'daysOfWeekDisabled' => [0-6],
           'pluginOptions' => [
               'dateFormat'=> date('Y-m-d'),
               'defaultDate' => $model->birthdate,
               'autoClose' => true,
               'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
               'firstday'=>1,
           ],
       ]);?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Могу поискать еще решения, поскольку для меня пока еще актуальна эта тема.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я попробовал ваш вариант и он сработал. У меня не работал плагин от kartik из-за кофликтов в css файлах, из-за x-editable.